# Currying and closure?

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble understanding the behavior of this code. The num parameter and array parameter seem to be acting differently and I am not sure what is causing it. So, the num parameter keeps track of how many times the curried function has been called, and you can go back up the curry chain and it will retain the correct num and let you go back down the chain with a new input. I would think that array would act the same way, but array keeps accumulating inputs and I am not sure what is causing it as like num, I am binding whatever its current value is just like I am with num.

```
function curryN(fn, n) {
    n = n || fn.length;
    return function curried(num, array, input) {
        console.log(array);
        num = num || n;
        array.push(input);
        num--;
        console.log(num);
        while (num >= 1) {
            return curried.bind(this, num, array)
        }
        var tempArray = array;
        return fn.apply(this, tempArray)
    }.bind(this, n, [])
}

function abc(one, two, three) {
    return one/two/three;
}

var curryC = curryN(abc),
    curryB = curryC(81),
    curryA = curryB(9);
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're attempting to do here.  One random guess is that `var tempArray = array;` isn't doing what you think it's doing - it's not cloning the array for instance, they will both be holding references to the _exact same array_.

Comment: @JamesThorpe This is a challenge from Nodeschool's Functional Javascript Workshop. I am not so much concerned with what the correct answer is at the moment, but how to improve my understanding of why my attempt at the answer is behaving in a way I do not understand. For instance, I set curryC = curryN(abc), and curryN(abc) returns curried.bind(this, n, []), so the 'array' parameter should be [] and it is the first time curryC is called, but why if I call curryC again is the array is no longer the bound [] but an array with whatever parameter I called the first time?

Answer (score -2):

Im not entirely sure what you are asking, but I think you are asking why when you push letters into the array, they appear as numbers.

If you are pushing a string to that array, wrap it in quotes so that the compiler knows you want the letters stored as a string, and not its numerical equivalent. Normally values don't need to be typed in Javascript, but if you are using an mixed array you need to let the compiler know you want it to remain a string.

for example,

```
var curryC = curryN(abc)
```

should be

```
var curryC = curryN("abc")
```

If this is completely not what you are asking, then please explain what desired output you are looking for.

Comment: `abc` is a function reference.

Comment: abc is the function he is trying to curry